# How to use MethodInvoker on Dynamic (RichTextBox)TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms

```
var currentTxt = (RichTextBox)TabControl_Query
  .SelectedTab
  .Controls
  .Find("RTX" + TabControl_Query.SelectedTab.TabIndex, true)
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

I am using a `BackgroundWorker`, also my Tabcontrol is dynamic so i can add new ones with a click (not static), i can use the example below on some physical existent Textboxes, labels, grids and whatever

```
TXT_SearchResults.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => TXT_SearchResults.Visible = true));
```

Now i can add new tabs without an issue but when i run the text inside the tab that contains a dynamic RichTextBox i will have the issue
[Program Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhHIO.jpg)

I get the following exception

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39KWz.jpg)

Comment: Please do not put text content in an image - an exception's content is just text, so please put it in the question (and not in a comment either).

Comment: the issue was my upload was restricted due to the network i am connected to, fixed the img(s)